# Import raw data from web page as a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to import some data from a webpage into a dataframe.

Data: a block of text in the following format

```
[{"ID":0,"Name":"John","Location":"Chicago","Created":"2017-04-23"}, ... ]
```

I am successfully making the request to the server and can return the data in text form, but cannot seem to convert this to a DataFrame.

E.g

```
r = requests.get(url)
people = r.text
print(people)
```

So from this point, I am a bit confused on how to structure this text as a DataFrame. Most tutorials online seem to demonstrate importing csv, excel or html etc.

Answer (score 1):

If `people` is a list of dict in string format, you can use `json.loads` to convert it to a list of dict and then create a DataFrame easily

```
>>> import json
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> people='[{"ID":0,"Name":"John","Location":"Chicago","Created":"2017-04-23"}]'
>>> json.loads(people)
[{'ID': 0, 'Name': 'John', 'Location': 'Chicago', 'Created': '2017-04-23'}]
>>> 
>>> data=json.loads(people)
>>> pd.DataFrame(data)
      Created  ID Location  Name
0  2017-04-23   0  Chicago  John
```

Comment: Works. Thank you. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? E.g is it necessary to first import the data as text after making the url request, to then load that text as JSON, before converting to a DataFrame. Seems a lot of variables being declared for a relatively simple exercise?

Comment: If you can directly get the page data in json, you can skip the step to convert the string to json.

Try `pd.DataFrame(r.json)`